# cannot copy leading zero

Tags: excel, ssis, null, numbers, zero

I'm using SSIS package to move data from Excel to SQL Database. 
Within the Data flow task I have Excel as source - Data Conversion - Ole DB Destination.

When it comes to data, I have these values in column:

Column
111
222
033

After running the task, all data are transferred successfully, however the last value 033 doesn't get through and there is NULL instead. I've noticed that it always happens when there is leading zero.

Do you know how can I adjust it so it gets in?

Note, I must use DT_WSTR in data conversion for this particular field because it is required in the destination table.

THx

Comment: Your Excel source component most likely sees the 033 as an INT. Because of this, it ignores the leading 0. Try going into advances editor and changing the datatype to (unicode) string

Comment: I've tried that, but still the issue occurs. The DataType was set before as double-precision DT_R8. So I've changed that to DT_STR as you advised, but no luck, I've also tried DT_WSTR, but no luck... :-(